# Where do I put this logic in this simple MVC scenario?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, mvvm, viewmodel

I will describe the problem I have to solve, and then ask my questions.

### Problem

My problem is pretty simple, or so it seems.  I need to hit the database, and get back a collection of sport Transaction entities.  These include things like "Denver Nuggets traded PlayerX for PlayerY".  Once I have a colleciton of Transaction entities, I need to output the content to a .txt file in a particular format, that is roughly like the following:

```
Title
  Sport1
    League1
      Transaction1
      Transaction2
      ...
    League2
      Transaction1
      Transaction2
  Sport2
  etc.
```

The ordering of the sports and leagues matter.  First comes Baseball, then Football, etc.  If a sport has no transactions, nothing is including in the file for the sport.  That's pretty much the program.

I am using an ORM, and the Transaction entity is very large with a lot of extra fields that I will not need to display.  For this reason, I would like to map to a viewmodel with only the information above.

### Questions

Firstly,  there is no 'domain' here, and so no need for a decomposed domain Transaction object, right?  All I need to do is map from a database entity to a ViewModel?

Secondly, how much 'view' logic do I encode in the repository method call?  Do I get back a colleciton of Transaction entities, and then sort them in my controller?  Or should the repository do this sorting for me?  I feel like if I let the repository class sort my Transactions according to the order I need them for the view, then that's spreading view logic around, which is confusing.  On the other hand, there is a performance benefit from letting the database do the sorting.

Thirdly, how much work does the controller do in terms of constructing the view model?  For example, and like I said above, any sport without a transaction should not be displayed at all.  Should the controller check and specifically exclude these transactions from the view model, or should the view make that check and decision?

Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Basically, you define the bussines/view logic meaning of your application. If order or visibility are main functionalities of your app, I wouldn't consider it view-logic. Even the DB sorting seems ok to me.

Answer (score 2):

> Firstly, there is no 'domain' here, and so no need for a decomposed
>   domain Transaction object, right? All I need to do is map from a
>   database entity to a ViewModel?

sounds OK to me

> Secondly, how much 'view' logic do I encode in the repository method
>   call? Do I get back a colleciton of Transaction entities, and then
>   sort them in my controller? Or should the repository do this sorting
>   for me? I feel like if I let the repository class sort my Transactions
>   according to the order I need them for the view, then that's spreading
>   view logic around, which is confusing. On the other hand, there is a
>   performance benefit from letting the database do the sorting.

I think sorting in the DB is ok, since it's better for performance. How much "view"? Depends on the view. See the next answer.

> Thirdly, how much work does the controller do in terms of constructing
>   the view model? For example, and like I said above, any sport without
>   a transaction should not be displayed at all. Should the controller
>   check and specifically exclude these transactions from the view model,
>   or should the view make that check and decision?

You're dumping to text, so "view" here is just the number of tabs or spaces you'll add to indent. But what if it was a GUI tree component? Then you'd have to push the data into nodes and provide info about what node is son of what node, and then you'd have work for your controller.

I think the main idea of MVC is to make it easier to switch each component. I mean, your MVC is well designed if, to replace a typical tree visualization from pure text to a GUI Tree component for example is easy. If it's not, maybe the layers are still too coupled and you can't properly reuse other layers.

Comment: You make a good point that I needed to hear:  If something is hard to change, then it probably can do with a refactor.  If it is easy to make a change, then it's probably OK.  I always wished there was a repeatable solution to every problem in software development, but I'm realizing more and more that the context of the problem determines the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, there is no 'domain' here, and so no need for a decomposed
>   domain Transaction object, right? All I need to do is map from a
>   database entity to a ViewModel?

Do you mean Data Transfer Object (DTO)? If you cross boundaries you still may need them (i.e. db > repository > webservice > repository > your app). From webservice to your app you cross boundaries, so you may need DTOs to reduce the data.

> Secondly, how much 'view' logic do I encode in the repository method
>   call? Do I get back a colleciton of Transaction entities, and then
>   sort them in my controller? Or should the repository do this sorting
>   for me? I feel like if I let the repository class sort my Transactions
>   according to the order I need them for the view, then that's spreading
>   view logic around, which is confusing. On the other hand, there is a
>   performance benefit from letting the database do the sorting.

Repository should be there for obtaining data. Whether or not using sort in Repository depends on what you want to do.

Do you want to sort it only by "Sport" and then by "League", then by i.e. "transaction date"? Then it's fine to do it in the repository, ihmo.

Do you want it to bring your data into a tree structure? Then no. This should be encapsulated in a service. The service receives an instance of your repository and you may have a `public PlayerTransactionsViewModel PlayerTransactionsService.GetAllTransactions()` or something like that in your service. The service then queries for all the transactions data and transforms it into your ViewModel

> Thirdly, how much work does the controller do in terms of constructing
>   the view model? For example, and like I said above, any sport without
>   a transaction should not be displayed at all. Should the controller
>   check and specifically exclude these transactions from the view model,
>   or should the view make that check and decision?

Controller actions should be very small and mainly wrap calls to the view. You should have no construction logic at all, except assigning a few values (i.e. mapping from Service to ViewModel... except if your service already returns a ViewModel of course).

Here may want to work with Data Transfer Objects, to reduce the data which is fetched from Repository and passed to the service.

As in reply to 2nd Question, you should use a service to encapsulate logic from controller and limit your controller to simple calls as

```
PlayerTransactionsViewModel viewModel = playerTransactionService.GetAllTransactions();
return View(viewModel);
```

But since you are writing a text file (I assume to the file system) there is actually no View involved at all and you can do that in the service too